# Updating a related Entity tries to add a new related Entity

Tags: entity-framework

When updating `myItem1` the related entity `Entity2` doesn't update but `EF` tries to add a new `Entity2`.  It throws a primary key constraint error.  `MyItem` has a `many-to-one` relationship with `Entity2`

```
public HttpResponseMessage PutMyItem(MyItem myitem)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            MyItem myItem1 = db.MyItems.First(m => m.MyItemId == myitem.MyItemId);
            myItem1.Name = myitem.Name;
            myItem1.Entity2 = myitem.Entity2;

            db.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(myItem1, EntityState.Modified);

            try
            {                    
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this line attaches `Entity2` to the context in the `Added` state. Setting the state of `myItem` to `Modified` doesn't affect its child entities...

```
myItem1.Entity2 = myitem.Entity2;
```

If you are sure this is a valid entity that already exists in the database, change its state to `Modified`...

```
db.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(myItem1.Entity2, EntityState.Modified);
```

Also, there shouldn't be a need to mark `myItem1` as `Modified`, as it should already in `Modified` state when its `Name` property was set.

Comment: That works.  Do you have to do this for all related entities?  Or is this just for `many-to-one` relationships?

Comment: In most cases, yes. In a web scenario where different contexts are used to read and write entities, unfortunately a lot of the change tracking mechanisms in EF don't work and you have to do a bit more work to make sure things are in the correct states.